# Non Parametric AB Test, marketing campaign

Tags: nonparametric, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, ab-test

The data is from real time digital marketing campaigns. We setup two paths A and B at the impression level. When a user sees an add, it is counted as an impression.
Now we had 1 lac impression at both the paths. However finally 29 players got converted. The data for the same is below:

Path A Revenue Data:
5084, 200, 54, 56, 98, 101, 2590, 45, 789,987,286,198,276,9807,235,765,389,1876,199,888

Path B Revenue Data:
6789, 987, 8890, 56, 78, 187, 14879, 798, 876, 22879

Concerns:
We cannot use the Wilcoxon test directly for the following reasons:

Both the paths have unequal number of conversions. And we need to penalise the path which has brought the lower number of conversions. However it is not possible because wilcoxon does not do the same.
Our high value players are the one which drives the business, its like 90:10 ratio. 10% of people bring 90% of revenue. Now Wilcoxon does not treat extreme values with the proper weightage.

Plans:
We were planning to add 9 players with zero revenue to path B and then run wilcoxon. In this way we are going to penalise the path B bringing lesser players. I don't know if it is right.
We were planning to discount the revenue of second path B with the multiplying factor of 10/19 to compensate for the lesser players being brought. I don't know if it is right.

Please let me know in case of any query.